# How do I get all the items names in a string

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I have created a database using `Sqflite` and I have column named `Item_name` and `Item_qty`. The thing is that I wanna get all the `Items_name and Item_qty` of the database in a String.

Like this: 
`Pens: 5`
`Book: 3`
`Phone: 2`

Will be very happy to see your suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `map` and get a string or you can similarly create a `List` and return the list.

```
Future<Map> getItemsQuantities() async {
  var databaseClient = //get your database 
  List<Map> list = await databaseClient.rawQuery('Select * from YourTableName');
  Map map = new Map();
  for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    map['${list[i]["Items_name"]}']= '${list[i]["Item_qty"]}';
  }
  return map;
}
```